# c++ why do i get errors when using ternary operator

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, ternary

So here's my code, and I just can't find what's wrong.
I would very much appreciate any help!

```
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x,I=2;

    for (x = 100 ; x <= 500; x++)
    {
        (x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0)? (cout << x << endl) : (I = 2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

errors:

[image]

Update:
I know I could use if ,else but it just made me curios, btw this program is supposed to find all numbers divisible by 3 and 5 from 100 to 500.
Also if I run

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x,I=2;

    for (x = 100 ; x <= 500; x++)
    {
        ((x % 3 == 0) && (x % 5 == 0))? (cout << x << endl) : (cout<<"somthing");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine so I guess the problem was in the second expression, is there a way to replace it with something that does nothing(that was the intent of I=2)

Comment: It is unclear what the variable I is doing here.

Comment: Because that's not the way how to use the ternary operator. What's wrong with simply using `if() else` BTW?

Comment: Consider reading this reference about the conditional operator: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator . That said, what would be the purpose of `(I = 2)` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ternary operator is not an if-else. It's for doing something like this:

```
int i = (3 < 4) ? 3 : 4;
```

Please use if-else for this usage.